# Use controller view for email view CakePHP 2

Tags: cakephp, view, cakephp-2.0

What is a good way to **use a controller action's view as an email template**? Currently have have two separate views: one in `../View/Emails/html/example.ctp` and one in `../View/Example/example.ctp`. This is too wet and is giving me headaches.

**Q.** What is the best way to dry this up and use the same template for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Controller` has a `render` method you may call explicitly
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#rendering-a-specific-view
and pass a `../path/to/email/template`

or you may extract a common element:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements